# WordPress live radio streaming in header frame issue

Tags: wordpress, frame, internet-radio

In order to implment continuous live radio player,
Having a WordPress instance,
I migrate it to sub folder **/main/**
on top of that I used frameset so that top frame have radio to continuous playing.
The issue is embedded YouTube doesn't allow full screen.
Can you advice.
I didn't find a plugin that support live radio without a popup.
Please refer to image attachment.

[image]

Some additional info:

```
<html>

<head>

<title></title>
<style>
.resp {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
</style>
</head>

<frameset class="resp"  rows="50,100%" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" style="width: 100%" >
    <frame class="resp" name="header" scrolling="no" src="radio.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" target="_self" width="100%">
    <frame  class="resp"  name="main" src="///WORDPRESS_PATH" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%">
    <noframes>
    <body>

    <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>

    </body>
    </noframes>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Whatever I do , the video player says I am not allowed to open full screen
But when I navigate to WordPress instance out of frames (directly), it works
so only within frames it dosn't work!

Comment: is the "allowfullscreen" parameter included in your embed code for that YouTube video?

Comment: Yes, 'allowfullscreen' is there

Comment: What could be the problem? is loading Youtube ifram within a frameset prohibited?

Comment: I think generally speaking, you'd have better luck just loading the player in an <iframe> element, rather than trying to use framesets and frames. Framesets are a bear to work with, and iFrames will give you more flexibility in styling and positioning.

Comment: Thank you Greg, that was the solution for me...Iframe, I wonder if you can convert your comment into an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think generally speaking, you'd have better luck just loading the player in an  element, rather than trying to use framesets and frames. Framesets are a bear to work with, and iFrames will give you more flexibility in styling and positioning.

Comment: Thank you Greg, would be there any security concern with using iframes, over a wordpress instance?